# string contain many '\0' after inflate

Tags: php, c++, zlib

I try to decompress blocks of data which were compressed with zlib and author made remarks that for decompress i must use `inflate_init` and `inflate` with `Z_SYNC_FLUSH`. I sure that this must work because that works on php in this way :

```
$temp = substr($temp, 2, -4);
$temp{0} = chr(ord($temp{0}) | 1);
$temp = gzinflate($temp);
```

but i ckecked many method for decompress this on C++ and every time fail. 
Here is one of them :

```
char compressedblockbuffer[3371];
char uncompressedblockbuffer[8192];

is.read(compressedblockbuffer, 3371);

z_stream strm;
strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
strm.zfree = Z_NULL;
strm.opaque = Z_NULL;
strm.avail_in = 3371;
strm.next_in = (Bytef *)compressedblockbuffer;
strm.avail_out = 8192;
strm.next_out = (Bytef *)uncompressedblockbuffer;

inflateInit(&strm);
inflate(&strm, Z_SYNC_FLUSH);
inflateEnd(&strm);
```

It's not full code, just example to show problem and thats why i specified already known sizes.
I use last zlib realize so may be something change in the zlib inflate since 2003-2004 years?
So the result is :
[image]
[image]

So seems that `uncompressedblockbuffer` contains '\0' at the 2,3,4 indexes and many other and if i print this to console i just see two first elements.

**UPD:**
[image]

Comment: You are not checking _any_ return codes from the `inflate*` routines!  How do you know they are even doing anything?  If a routine returns a code to indicate it's success or failure, then you must _always_ check it.

Comment: @Mark Adler, i checked it in full code and there was no errors and return code is Z_OK, but anyway this doesn't metter in this case bacause otherwise `uncompressedblockbuffer` will be empty.

Comment: So `inflate()` is not returning `Z_STREAM_END`?  Are you looking at `avail_in` and `avail_out` after the operation?  What are they?  There is no such thing as an "empty" buffer.  It is either uninitialized, in which case it has whatever the operating system left in it, or it is previously used, in which case it has whatever you left in it.

Comment: @Mark Adler, look at updated in the question, please. What does it mean, why `avail_out` and `avil_in` are `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `gzinflate()` in PHP works on the data, then your code won't.  `gzinflate()` expects raw deflate data.  Your code is looking for zlib-wrapped deflate data.  If you want to decode raw deflate data, you need to use `inflateInit2(&strm, -15)` instead.

Your call to `inflate()` is likely returning an error that you are not checking for.  You need to always check the return codes of the zlib routines, or for that matter any function that has the potential to return an error.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of data are you decompressing? Many binary formats are perfectly accepting of NUL bytes in their data, since it just reads as a value of 0. For example, inside of image data in many formats, it'd just represent a value of 0 in either that channel or pixel (depending on data size). Not to mention, binary formats don't necessarily read as bytes. A NUL byte may actually be a part of a 2- or 4-byte value.

This is the problem with trying to read binary data as a character string. Binary data needn't follow the rules of text. This is why usually the data boundary is a separate `size` value, because it can't terminate on NUL values like text.

If you have the original uncompressed data for comparison, either load that data into memory and compare the data, or save the decompressed data to a file and use a diff tool to do a binary comparison of the files.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I can operate with buffer but can't print him and this really confused me for two days).
compressed c++   http://pastebin.com/CWdymMUU#    
uncompressed c++ http://pastebin.com/wVvgRc4P#    
compressed php   http://pastebin.com/99KDdMgn#      
uncompressed php http://pastebin.com/5q6eBybd#   

So they are a little bit different.